# MPMoviePlayerController into a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to play a video into a cocos2d project.. and my question is: how can I put MPMoviePlayerController into my view like this:?

```
UIView *theView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
```

thanks very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put controllers into views. However, you can put the views that they control into a view. Try this:

```
// instantiate and configure your MPMoviePlayerController here, c
// call it movieController

[theView addSubview:movieController.view];
```

disclaimer: I'm at the office so I have no way of knowing if this will work.